# Using NSHashTable to implement Observer pattern in Swift 3

Tags: swift, delegates, swift3, observer-pattern

Adding multiple delegates instead of only one is a quite common task. Suppose we have protocol and a class:

```
protocol ObserverProtocol
{
   ...
}

class BroadcasterClass
{
    // Error: Type 'ObserverProtocol' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
    private var _observers = NSHashTable<ObserverProtocol>.weakObjects()
}
```

If we try to force `ObserverProtocol` to conform `AnyObject` protocol, we will get another error:

> Using 'ObserverProtocol' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'AnyObject' is not supported

Is it even possible to create a set of weak delegates in Swift 3.0?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, it's possible.

`AnyObject` is the Swift equivalent of `id` in Objective C. To get your code to compile, you just need to add the `@objc` annotation to your protocol, to tell Swift that the protocol should be compatible with Objective C.

So:

```
@objc protocol ObserverProtocol {

}
```